# What is the meaning of "aruga aruga'

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

In Ben Aaronovitch's *Foxglove Summer*, the main character exclaims this (mentally) upon thinking he's discovered an important clue in an interview. What is the meaning of the phrase?

> I felt her mother practically start out of her chair, and then subside again.
>   'What did it feel like?' I asked.
>   'Like a big tongue,' said Gaby.
>   'And was it low down or high up?'
>   Gaby jumped off her chair and demonstrated by sticking her arm straight out in front of her with her palm turned up. About a metre twenty above floor level, by the way she held her hand, suggested an animal of some kind.
>   'What kind of animal is Princess Luna?' I asked.
>   'She's a pony, silly,' said Gaby brightly.
>   A little klaxon went off in my head.
>   ***Aruga aruga***, I thought. ***Set condition one throughout the ship***.

Comment: It's a representation of the sound of a klaxon.

Answer (score 2):

It's an onomatopoea for the sound of an alarm (klaxon). "Aruga," "A-ooga," "Awooga" or other spellings are all ways a writer might represent the sound; onomatopoetic words often don't have a standardized spelling.

Comment: It's literally within the text you posted: "A little klaxon went off in my head. Aruga aruga" It's the sound of the "little klaxon," the alarm, that was mentioned immediately beforehand.

Comment: Urban dictionary is not trustworthy. The other answer has been downvoted because it is not at all correct, and does not take into consideration any contextual clues.

Comment: It means what it says. I know no other way to explain it; it's a phrasing completely devoid of subtlety or multiple interpretations. The author says an alarm goes off, then has the alarm go off. It's no more subtle than "'I'm sad,' he said sadly."

Answer (score -4):

The urban dictionary https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=aruga
says it’s from the Marines and expresses agreement, like saying “Yes Yes Yes!”